# Approximating cube root function for small values of $x$

Tags: calculus, power-series

How can one show that for small values of $x$, $\sqrt[3]{x+1}\approx1+\frac{x}{3}$?

Comment: Did you try Taylor series?

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: yes, but I still don't see the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, look at the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+1}$ in the vicinity of $0$.
$$
f'(x) = ((x+1)^{1/3})' = \frac{1}{3}(x+1)^{-2/3}.
$$
So $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0) = 1/3$. Then $f(x)=f(0) + f'(0)\cdot x + o(x)$, that is
$$
\sqrt[3]{1+x} = 1 + \frac{x}{3} + o(x).
$$
I guess this is what we wanted. Unfortunately, this doesn't really give you any meaningful information in terms of percision.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+ \frac{x}{3})^3 = 1 + 3 \frac{x}{3} (1) ( \frac{x}{3} +1 ) + \frac{x^3}{3^3} = 
 1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{x^3 }{27}$ So since $x$ is small $1+ \frac{x}{3}$ is approximately same to $(1+x)^\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a>b>0$. Then:
$$3b^2\leq \frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}=a^2+ab+b^2\leq 3a^2, $$
$$ (a-b)\leq\frac{a^3-b^3}{3b^2}.$$
Now plug in the last inequality $a=1+x/3$ and $b=(1+x)^{1/3}$:
$$ (1+x/3)-(1+x)^{1/3} \leq \frac{x^2/3 + x^3/27}{(1+x)^{2/3}}.$$
If $x\geq 0$ you have:
$$ (1+x/3)-(1+x)^{1/3} \leq \frac{1}{3}\,x^2(1+x)^{1/3}.$$