# Proving $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac19}-\sqrt[3]{\frac29}+\sqrt[3]{\frac49}$

Tags: number-theory

I found the following two relational expressions in a book without any additional information:

$$\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{5}-\sqrt[3]{4}}=\frac13(\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{20}-\sqrt[3]{25})$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac19}-\sqrt[3]{\frac29}+\sqrt[3]{\frac49}$$

Wolfram tells these are true, but I can't prove at all. Can anyone help?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233553/approximating-cube-root-function-for-small-values-of-x for inspiration.

Comment: @IanColey : I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: @mathlove Same here: how does it help?

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I misunderstood it.

Comment: These identities are all very famous and Ramanujan had many more examples of this sort. The identities can be proven with some tedious algebra, but the best thing to note is that these numbers are units in a certain field and Ramanujan was keenly interested in radicals which were units. Search for keyword "Ramanujan" in wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For the identity in the title, use the identity $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$, then $(x^2-x+1)(x+1)=x^3+1=3$ hence the RHS is $\sqrt[3]{3}/(x+1)$ and the LHS divided by the RHS is the cube root of one third of $(x-1)(x+1)^3=(x^3-2)(x+2)+3$. Since $x^3=2$, this is $3$ and the result follows.

> For the other identity:

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{5/4}$, then the identity to prove is $3\sqrt{x-1}=1+2x-2x^2$. Squaring both sides, this is equivalent to $1+4(x-x^2)+4(x-x^2)^2-9(x-1)=(5-4x^3)(2-x)$ being zero. Since $4x^3=5$, the result follows.

Answer (score 7):

let

> $$\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{3}}=x,\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{3}}=y$$
>   then
>   $$\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{9}}-\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{9}}+\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{4}{9}}=x^2-xy+y^2$$

then

> $$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=x^3+y^3=\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}=1$$
>   $$\Longrightarrow x^2-xy+y^2=\dfrac{1}{x+y}=\sqrt[3]{3}(\sqrt[3]{1}+\sqrt[3]{2})^{-1}=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}$$

Comment: Nice solution china math........